# What happens at the compiler level when I dereference a pointer to pass it by reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm interested in what the compiler does when I dereference a pointer explicitly to pass it by reference:

```
void foo(A& arg)
{
   arg.member = 7;
}

void goo()
{
   A* ob = new A();
   foo(*ob);
   printf(ob->member); // should show 7
}
```

The reason I'm interested is because I believe bringing the dereference out of the function call would create very different behavour:

```
void foo(A& arg)
{
   arg.member = 7;
}

void goo()
{
   A* ob = new A();
   A ob_dereferenced = *ob;
   foo(ob_dereferenced);
   printf(ob->member); // should show whatever A initialises member to
}
```

Comment: `A ob_dereferenced = *ob;` creates a copy. This is not what the first version of the code does

Comment: Have you checked the assembly?  That'd tell you for sure what's happening, including as you change optimization levels.

Comment: Ok, so it's the "A ob_dereferenced ="  which creates the copy.  *ob is just the reference.  Thanks, maybe the question is too simple.

Comment: In a way not much, the compiled code is probably going to look the same or very similar (references are pointers too, just with some extra rules on how they can be used and that they promise to refer to a valid object)

Comment: In your example you have a memory leak. Just make `A ob;` as local variable or use `std::make_unique<A>();` (you should hardly have to use new/delete in current C++ code anyway)

Comment: `A& ob_dereferenced = *ob` is a no-op for the compiler. The actual dereference will happen when your code actually uses `ob_dereferenced`.

Comment: @Botje   That's not necessarily true.   If `ob` is reassigned (to point at a different object) after `ob_dereferenced` is initialised, subsequent usage of `ob_dereferenced` will still refer to the original pointee.   A compiler that does otherwise would be a buggy compiler.

Comment: Right, "no-op" was a bit too strong. I should have said it copies the pointer value instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is not a fair one because here in the second version:

> ```
> void goo()
> {
>    A* ob = new A();
>    A ob_dereferenced = *ob;   // <---- here !!!
>    foo(ob_dereferenced);
>    printf(ob->member); // should show whatever A initialises member to
> }
> ```

You are making a copy of the `A` instance. Depending on what `A` is, creating a second instance can have observable side effects.

However, lets put such observable side effects aside, and use

```
 struct A { int member = 0; };
```

then there is no observable difference between:

```
 void moo(A* a) { 
      foo(*a);    
 }
```

and using a local reference:

```
 void moo(A* a) { 
      A& b = *a;  
      foo(b);
 }
```

Those two `moo` do the same. There is no reason to expect different output from the compiler when optimizations are turned on.

PS: Your both versions leak memory. If you need a pointer for an example you do not need `new`. For example `A a; A* aptr = &a;` makes up for a totally fine pointer to `A` and you dont need to worry about leaks. Above I avoided the issue, by simply assuming the pointer comes from *somewhere*.